# Dificuldade com callback e arrow function

Tags: javascript, callback, arrow-functions

Boa noite,

Estou aprendendo JS e cheguei na parte de callback e arrow functions. Escrevi um código onde existe uma arrow function que roda através de uma estrutura for os índices de dois arrays e define se o mesmo índice é maior ou menor que o outro array (em valor do índice).

```
    let Alice = [23, 67, 32]
let Bob = [12, 67, 43]
let Hans = [34, 24, 42]

let playerA = 0
let playerB = 0

let calcPoints = (a, b) => {
  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    if (a[i] == b[i]) {
      return
      // ROUND DRAW! console.log("Player A points increased by one. Now it's " + playerA)
    } else if (a[i] < b[i]) {
      playerB = playerB + 1
      // console.log("Player B points increased by one. Now it's " + playerB)
      return playerB
    } else if (a[i] > b[i]) {
      playerA = playerA + 1
      return playerA
    }
  }
}
```

E então depois tem uma função que usa como callback a função acima e tem o objetivo de definir qual o ganhador.

```
let findWinner = (playerA, playerB, c) => {
  c(playerA, playerB)
  if (playerA == playerB) {
    console.log(
      "Unfortunately the prize will be shared since the participants has tie'd the competition"
    )
  } else if (playerB > playerA) {
    console.log('Player B won the match! WINNER WINNER CHICKEN DINNER!')
  } else if (playerA > playerB) {
    console.log('Player A won the match! WINNER WINNER CHICKEN DINNER!')
  }
}

findWinner(Bob, Alice, calcPoints)
```

Porém, ao executar no Node, o resultado do exemplo (Bob,Alice) me retorna que "Player B" ganhou, porém, ao analisar os arrays declarados, Bob e Alice sofrem um empate.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui, realizei testes com a função primária calcPoints e ela estava correta, sem "bugs".

Alterei os parâmetros, e chamei a função calcPoints no início da função que a usa como callback e consegui resolver. Função calcPoints:

```
let calcPoints = (a, b) => {
  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    if (a[i] == b[i]) {
    } else if (a[i] < b[i]) {
      playerB = playerB + 1
    } else if (a[i] > b[i]) {
      playerA = playerA + 1
    }
  }
}
```

Função alterada e corrigida:

```
let findWinner = (a, b, c) => {
  c(a, b)
  if (playerA == playerB) {
    console.log(
      "Unfortunately the prize will be shared since the participants has tie'd the competition"
    )
  } else if (playerB > playerA) {
    console.log('Player B won the match! WINNER WINNER CHICKEN DINNER!')
  } else if (playerA > playerB) {
    console.log('Player A won the match! WINNER WINNER CHICKEN DINNER!')
  }
}

findWinner(Bob, Alice, calcPoints)
```

O resultado obtido ao executar no node.js no exemplo (Bob, Alice) é o esperado: "Unfortunately the prize will be shared since the participants has tie'd the competition".